# Estimate of installed size from scripts

Tags: texlive, installing

I want to install a leaner version for creating pdf files from tex files. I especially want to avoid documentation and support for non-english languages.

I want to know if [this script](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/master/support/texlive.sh) or [this one](https://github.com/BPA-CSIRO-Workshops/handout-template/blob/master/developers/texlive_install.sh), which are to install leaner versions of texlive, can give an estimate of disk usage before actually installing the packages?

Comment: This really depends on the file you want to compile. If it's a template which package list is a page long you will have to install more stuff then if it's very short. And you can also omit some binaries if necessary, but it depends on your use case.

Answer (score 3):

If you install vanilla texlive via the command line (e.g. from https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) you can de-select things like documentation and languages you don't need. At the bottom you will always see the required size for your selection:

[image]

[image]